# Tag lts-3.1 not found pulling to docker a fresh yesod scaffold

Tags: yesod, haskell-stack

I'm trying to deploy a simple yesod web site using `stack docker`.

My steps:

1. `stack yesod init` ... `stack exec -- yesod devel` works fine.
2. `export DOCKER_HOST=myhost` and test `docker info` runs ok.
3. add `docker: \n enable: true` to `stack.yaml`.

Then, **fail**

```
$ stack docker pull
Pulling image from registry: 'fpco/stack-build:lts-3.1'
Pulling repository docker.io/fpco/stack-build
Tag lts-3.1 not found in repository docker.io/fpco/stack-build
Could not pull Docker image:
    fpco/stack-build:lts-3.1
There may not be an image on the registry for your resolver's LTS version in stack.yaml.
```

I'm using

```
$ stack exec -- ghc --version
The Glorious Glasgow Haskell Compilation System, version 7.10.2
```

I know

> Not every LTS version is guaranteed to have an image existing, and new
>   LTS images tend to lag behind the LTS snapshot being published on
>   stackage.org. Be warned: these images are rather large!

My first goal is **use `stack docker`** and to know if I do something wrong.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For the moment, use a resolver setting in your stack.yaml that matches one of the available tags, such as `resolver: lts-2.22` (see https://hub.docker.com/r/fpco/stack-build/tags/ for a list).  I'm working on LTS 3.x images, but have run into some trouble building all the packages in it, and debugging has gone slowly due to how long it takes to build all of Stackage.

Comment: FYI: I've now set things up so that as soon as a new LTS release is pushed to the https://github.com/fpco/lts-haskell repo, it will trigger an automatic build of the fpco/stack-build image.  That means, unless there are problems with the build, new images should be available a short time after the LTS snapshot becomes available.